# Apache Pig - dispose of intermdiate aliases?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm writing what's turning out to be a lengthy Pig Latin script containing many operations.  Sometimes the only purpose of an operation is to get to an intermediate relation `X` which is later transformed or enriched into `Y`, at which `X` stops being of interest.  Does Pig keep `X` materialised somewhere (e.g. in memory or in HDFS) and should I be worried about "freeing" `X`?  Or is this taken care of between Pig and Hadoop?

Bonus question: if there are any interesting differences when it comes to the runtime handling of such intermediate values between Pig on MapReduce, Pig on Tez and Pig on Spark it would be nice to learn about that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig Uses Lazy Execution to evaluate. Some features of lazy evaluation are

- processing only happens on DUMP/STORE command
- allows re-ordering for optimization
- in-memory pipelining

Pig interpreter calculates DAG once you submit your query. You can view your execution plan that pig uses by using **EXPLAIN** command in grunt shell.